# Is adding Homebrew's Python site-packages to macOS system a good idea?

Tags: python, homebrew, system-administration

When updating Homebrew I got the following warning:

```
==> Pouring py2cairo-1.15.4.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run:
  mkdir -p /Users/qazwsx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/qazwsx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

Should I do this? It seems to modify the Python installation that came with macOS, is doing that recommended normally?

When developing Java programs, I sometimes use virtualenv.

Comment: It ***does not*** modify the Python installation that came with macOS. What it does is it adds the system's `site-packages` folder to the list of searched directories by your homebrew's python installation. Your new python installation will point to the system's package directory.

Comment: So it's mostly safe and desirable, right?

Comment: Mostly safe, but desirable is up to you. I like to separate python installations to make sure that the removal of one does not cause issues with another. But given that the system's python version is ***never*** to be deleted, I guess this is fine.